# How to retrieve an existing auth token for a user?

Tags: box-api

Using the new token method of authentication in v2.0, is there a way to retrieve an existing token for a user?

Answer (score 0):

There currently is not, but we are working on developing a means of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

In the script I am working on, I save the XML file that is first returned when I get a `auth_token`. This way I can re-use it later.